# Centering li without adding margin to the last item?

Tags: html, css

I always follow this approach to centering a bunch of items, all having some margin

```css
li {
  float: left;
  margin: 50px;
}
ul {
  width: 420px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>
```

The problem with this, is that it adds margin to the last item as well, so it doesn't look perfectly centered. I want the first item to be in the very beginning of the `ul` and the last item to be at the end of the `ul`, how to make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Flexbox** and `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
ul {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this https://jsfiddle.net/07x0xyL3/2/

```
  li {
   float:left;
   margin: 50px 0 50px 100px;
  }
  li:first-child {
    margin: 50px 0;
  }
```

browser support http://htmlbook.ru/css/first-child

Answer (score 0):

You can try something `li:first-child {...}` and `li:last-child {...}`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11119576)

Comment: @SergueiFedorov This actually is a valid attempted answer. This post should not have been flagged and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Comment: @TinyGiant This fits to "try something like", which is better left as a comment to the original question.

Comment: It may most definitely be better as a comment, but that doesn't mean that it isn't an attempt to answer. It is an attempt to answer, so it should not have been flagged. Because you are reviewing based on whether or not it should have been flagged, and not whether or not you think it should be deleted, this should not have been recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. @SergueiFedorov

Comment: @TinyGiant this is a pointless argument. Thank you for your input, I promise to be more considerate next time.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is the answer width **`display: flex`** and then no need for floats

But if you want legacy(universal) do `display: table-cell`

[List centered](https://jsfiddle.net/y34gypfn/)

Answer (score 0):

the perfect solution to this, is to use `flexbox`:

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #FF9898;
  padding: 25px 0;
}
li{
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is Item</li>
  <li>This is Item</li>
  <li>This is Item</li>
  <li>This is Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your CSS section

```
li:first-child{margin-left: 0px;}
li:last-child{margin-right: 0px;}
```

Comment: Before anyone chooses to [recommend deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11119619) of this post, this is a valid attempted answer. This post should not have been flagged and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Comment: I really don't know why you are commenting this on my answer? Can you more elaborate please?

Comment: See the first link in my comment, this was flagged and subsequently sent to the review queue. Users there have a tendency to just recommend deletion for everything instead of actually reviewing the answers to the best of their ability, as such I was leaving the comment to hopefully stop those users from robo-deleting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float` add `inline-block` to `li` and `white-space: nowrap` to `ul`

```css
li {
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>
```